# SQL Server - Counting a column with conditions and also outputing percentages

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the real world situation:

There are cabins, identified by 'house'.  People can live in cabins. 'person_age' identifies each person's age.

I am trying to find out how many people older than 35 live in each cabin, and what percentage of people in that cabin are older than 35, with the condition that I only want to consider people who moved into the cabin in a particular date range, and I also want to know results per cabin.

I have the following query:

```
select
   [house]
  ,count(case when person_age > 35 then 1 end) as [older than 35]
  ,(cast(count(case when person_age > 35 then 1 end) as float))/(count(case when person_age > 35 then 1 else 1 end)) as [percent older than 35]
from cabins
where
  move_in_date >= '2014-02-01' 
  and move_in_date <= '2014-03-01'
group by [house]
```

Is there a better way to calculate the percentage field, such as a specific function or something?  It works, I think, but it's so ugly.

Am I using the count function correctly?  It gives me what I think I want, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `count(case when person_age > 35 then 1 else 1 end)` this part can be `count (1)`

Comment: I'm assuming you have a `GROUP BY` clause, otherwise the statement wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Gosh, you're right.  It's not there for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks ok in the logic.  I would write it like this instead:

```
select [house],
       sum(case when person_age > 35 then 1 else 0 end) as [older than 35],
       avg(case when person_age > 35 then cast(1 as float) else 0
           end) as [percent older than 35]
from cabins
where move_in_date >= '2014-02-01' and move_in_date <= '2014-03-01'
group by [house];
```

In other words, you can just create an indicator that has a value of 0.0 or 1.0 and use the `avg()` function.

Comment: I completely forgot about avg() function when I wrote my answer, but your answer (as well as the question) is missing the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting a non-aggregate along with two aggregates, so you'll need a `GROUP BY`, and you can use `OVER()` on the `SUM()` to get the `Percent of total`:

```
SELECT  [house]
      , COUNT(CASE WHEN person_age > 35 THEN 1 END) AS [older than 35]
      , COUNT(CASE WHEN person_age > 35 THEN 1 END)*1.0/SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN person_age > 35 THEN 1 END))OVER() AS [percent older than 35]
FROM    cabins
WHERE   move_in_date >= '2014-02-01'
        AND move_in_date <= '2014-03-01'
GROUP BY [house]
```

Update: Re-reading I think you want the percent of people over 35 per house, so simply:

```
SELECT  [house]
      , COUNT(CASE WHEN person_age > 35 THEN 1 END) AS [older than 35]
      , COUNT(CASE WHEN person_age > 35 THEN 1 END)*1.0/COUNT(person_age) AS [percent older than 35]
FROM    cabins
WHERE   move_in_date >= '2014-02-01'
        AND move_in_date <= '2014-03-01'
GROUP BY [house]
```

Comment: By the time I saw your comment, you had edited your answer! I downvoted because you posted code with no explanation. Changed to upvote because you added a good explanation.

Comment: Yeah, I edited the question with the `group by` clause that for some reason got left out.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems with your code:

1) these counts have no conditions, so they will give you the total count of people over 35 in ALL cabins and the percentage of people over 35 in ALL cabins (whereas what you want is these numbers in EACH cabin). To fix this, you'll need to add a "GROUP BY [house]" after your where clause. This will tell the aggregate functions (count and percentage) to only look at a given house for each row.

2) You don't need a case statement in the denominator of your percentage field. Count(*) does the same thing. It should look like this:

```
(cast(count(case when person_age > 35 then 1 end) as float))/(count(*)) as [percent older than 35]
```

edit: count(1) as @Darka suggests in the comments would also work.

Answer (score 1):

you could simplify it a little bit

```
select
   [house]
  ,count(case when person_age > 35 then 1 end) as [older than 35]
  ,(cast(count(case when person_age > 35 then 1 end) as float))/(count(1)) as [percent older than 35]
from cabins
where
  move_in_date between '2014-02-01' and '2014-03-01'
GROUP BY [house]
```

Comment: Your answer (as well as the original question) is missing the "group by" clause.

Comment: I put the `group by` back in.

Comment: Will the `count(1)` also count when the field is `null`?  (Which is what I would like.)  Also, I noticed that you put `count(1)` where Goat put `count(person_age)`.  Will they still count the same parts?

Comment: Count(1) will count all records no matter what. I prefer to use it then count(*), we are trying to count records, nothing else.